# Customizing Browser's Default Form Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input field through which user can submit some data. But he/she can't submit data if the character length is less than 10 chars.

```
<input type='text' minlength='10' id='input_text' />
```

But in case a user tries to submit data less than 10 chars long, then browser was showing an error. I tried to customize that error, through this code,

```
var data = document.getElementById("input_text");
data.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
    if (data.validity.typeMismatch) {
        data.setCustomValidity("Invalid Data.")
    } else {
        data.setCustomValidity("Your data is invalid.")
    }
})
```

But, the problem is that this code is not allowing users to submit data at all. It's showing an error `Your data is invalid` even when the character length is more than 10.

How can we fix this issue?

Thank You . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation) in your case you need to change your code to:

```js
var data = document.getElementById("input_text");
data.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
    if (data.validity.tooShort) { // test against min length
        data.setCustomValidity("Invalid Data."); // add error...
    } else {
        data.setCustomValidity(""); // remove error....
    }
})
```

```html
<form>
    <input type='text' minlength='10' id='input_text' />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Wow, this code is working fine. But sir, is it necessary to add the `else` statement in javascript?

Comment: Yes. It is necessary in order to remove error message and condition. Without that else you cannot submit the form because an error is set......